# Allow all URLs but one in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I would like to protect just a single URL, while allowing anonymous access for everything else.

The Java configuration examples i'm seeing in the internet all seem to indicate that you need to explicitly `permitAll` each and every URL, and appropriate `hasRole` for URLs that need to be protected. This in my case, creates a really unwieldy java code which I have modify every time I add a new URL to the application. Is there an easier java configuration that I can use.

And note also that in my case, the URL i'm protecting is a sub-resource, say `employee/me`, I would like `employee/list`, etc., to be anonymously accessible.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you're using *Java Configuration*, you can use something like following in your `configure` method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/employee/me").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
}
```

Comment: And it depends on the order. Putting the `"/**"` on the top overrides everything else.